# How to convert same Id Rows into columns with same header in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

The query I run to gerenate this dataset :

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAppointmentTable (
    UniqueID int,
    DateOfAppointment nvarchar(500),
    TypeOfAppointment nvarchar(500),
    AppointmentType nvarchar(500),
    VisitStage int
);
    
INSERT INTO #TempAppointmentTable
    ([UniqueID], [DateOfAppointment], [TypeOfAppointment], [AppointmentType],[VisitStage])
VALUES
    (82, '2022-03-10 00:00:00.000', 'a','d',1),
    (82, '2022-03-15 00:00:00.000', 'b','e',2),
    (82, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'c','f',3),
    (83, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'c','g',4),
    (83, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'c','h',5)
;
SELECT * FROM #TempAppointmentTable
    
DROP TABLE #TempAppointmentTable
```

I need to get an output that show every colomn over a single line for every `UniqueID` as shown below

[image]

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Will you always have the same number of "duplicate" uniqueIDs for each ID or is it variable? If it's variable, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible in SQL

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Are you actually looking to pivot the data in your application layer, and thus asking how to do this with C# code? What Stored Procedure is this SQL in, as you have also tagged [[tag:stored-procedures]].

Comment: @MatthewHart no same record maybe 10,15,20 and so on.

Comment: What for?  You have this data already so maybe the problem is how to show em ... fx you wana show it in datagrid (maybe that's why it has c# tag)... then you may create new DataTable based on this recordest and flat it ...

Comment: it's too much clear but i don't know why people down vote my question.

Comment: Is there any possibility to have more  than three rows for any UniqueID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the query using the `COUNT(*)` of your table.

It will `JOIN` each row to the first one until you have no row left

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAppointmentTable (
    UniqueID int,
    DateOfAppointment nvarchar(500),
    TypeOfAppointment nvarchar(500),
    AppointmentType nvarchar(500),
    VisitStage int
);
    
INSERT INTO #TempAppointmentTable
    ([UniqueID], [DateOfAppointment], [TypeOfAppointment], [AppointmentType],[VisitStage])
VALUES
    (82, '2022-03-10 00:00:00.000', 'a','d',1),
    (84, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'e','h',5),
    (84, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'f','i',5),
    (82, '2022-03-15 00:00:00.000', 'b','e',2),
    (82, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'c','f',3),
    (83, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'd','g',4),
    (84, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'g','j',5),
    (84, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'h','k',5),
    (84, '2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'i','l',5)
;

DECLARE @list_id TABLE (idx INT IDENTITY, id INT)
DECLARE @nb_rows INT
DECLARE @nb_cols INT
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @j INT = 0
DECLARE @cur_id INT
DECLARE @cur_nb_rows INT
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @list_id(id) SELECT [UniqueID] FROM #TempAppointmentTable GROUP BY [UniqueID] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
SELECT @nb_rows = COUNT(*) FROM @list_id;
SELECT @nb_cols = MAX(val) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempAppointmentTable GROUP BY [UniqueID])t(val);

SET @sql = '
WITH TMP ([Row], [UniqueID], [DateOfAppointment], [TypeOfAppointment], [AppointmentType],[VisitStage]) AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [UniqueID] ORDER BY UniqueID), * from #TempAppointmentTable
)'

WHILE @i < @nb_rows
BEGIN
    SELECT @cur_id = id FROM @list_id WHERE idx = @i+1
    SELECT @cur_nb_rows = COUNT(*) FROM #TempAppointmentTable WHERE [UniqueID] = @cur_id
    IF @i != 0 
        SET @sql = @sql + '
UNION'
    SET @sql = @sql + '
SELECT TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + '0.[UniqueID]'
    WHILE @j+1 < @nb_cols
    BEGIN
        IF @j < @cur_nb_rows
            SET @sql = @sql + ', TMP'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.[DateOfAppointment] AS [DateOfAppointment' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + ']'
                            + ', TMP'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.[TypeOfAppointment] AS [TypeOfAppointment' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + ']'
                            + ', TMP'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.[AppointmentType] AS [AppointmentType' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + ']'
                            + ', TMP'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.[VisitStage] AS [VisitStage' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + ']'
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL'
        SET @j = @j + 1
    END
    SET @j = 0
    SET @sql = @sql + '
FROM TMP AS TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + '0'
    WHILE @j+1 < @nb_cols
    BEGIN
        SET @j = @j + 1
        IF @j < @cur_nb_rows
            SET @sql = @sql + '
INNER JOIN TMP AS TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + ' ON TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.Row = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j+1) +' AND TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j) + '.UniqueID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@cur_id)
    END
    SET @sql = @sql + '
WHERE TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + '0.Row = 1 AND TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i) + '0.UniqueID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@cur_id)
    SET @j = 0
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

PRINT(@sql)

EXEC(@sql)

Drop table #TempAppointmentTable
```

The output looks like

| UniqueID | DateOfAppointment0 | TypeOfAppointment0 | AppointmentType0 | VisitStage0 | DateOfAppointment1 | TypeOfAppointment1 | AppointmentType1 | VisitStage1 | DateOfAppointment2 | TypeOfAppointment2 | AppointmentType2 | VisitStage2 | DateOfAppointment3 | TypeOfAppointment3 | AppointmentType3 | VisitStage3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82 | 2022-03-10 00:00:00.000 | a | d | 1 | 2022-03-15 00:00:00.000 | b | e | 2 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | c | f | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 83 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | d | g | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 84 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | e | h | 5 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | f | i | 5 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | g | j | 5 | 2022-03-20 00:00:00.000 | h | k | 5 |

Comment: I check your above code but this is not working for different unique ids.

Comment: Now the issue is if the id is different then this is also displayed on one row but I need every row for unique ids like 82 row,second is 83 row with all record in one row

Comment: Can you give the expected output for that case ?

Comment: Now i update the question (sql script and images) please check

Comment: SQL Updated, I let you check the code if you wanna order by number of elements DESC. With that I have the result you want. You can certainly optimize that query if you want.

Comment: Great! thanks brother I exactly want like this.